# discord.js bot status UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to change my Discord bot's status. I'm hopelessly lost trying to understand how promises work, which I think is part of the issue. Discord's `ready` also doesn't have parameters so it's probably taking issue there too, but I don't know where else I'd pass the client through.

This is significant code from `main.js`:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const fs = require('fs');

client.events = new Discord.Collection();

//EVENT HANDLING ================
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (client, ...args) => event.execute(client, ...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (client, ...args) => event.execute(client, ...args));
    }
}
...
```

Then line 13 calls `ready.js` on startup:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ready',
    once: true,
    execute(client) {

        console.log('Maika is online!');

        client.user.setActivity('music', { type: 'LISTENING' });
}
}
```

And below is the full error message.

```
    (node: 9624) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
at Object.execute(C: \Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\events\ready.js: 8: 16)
at Client.<anonymous>(C: \Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\main.js: 15: 54)
at Object.onceWrapper(events.js: 519: 28)
at Client.emit(events.js: 400: 28)
at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady(C: \Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js: 431: 17)
at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady(C: \Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js: 415: 10)
at WebSocketShard.<anonymous>(C: \Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js: 197: 14)
at WebSocketShard.emit(events.js: 400: 28)
at WebSocketShard.checkReady(C: \Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js: 475: 12)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket(C: \Users\Al\Desktop\MaikaBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js: 447: 16)
    (Use`node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
    (node: 9624) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag`--unhandled-rejections=strict`(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
        (node: 9624) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated.In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non - zero exit code.
```

Comment: implies `execute` is being called without an argument

Comment: oh, you realise that the `client` in `event.execute(client, ...args)` is NOT `const client = new Discord.Client();` right, it's the `client` from `(client, ...args)` event handler

Comment: try `client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(client, ...args));` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your execution code to this:

```js
if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(client, ...args));
    }
```

The [`ready`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready) event supplies no arguments in v12 ([v13](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready) gives the client that became ready). Therefore, `client` ends up undefined in that function. You will need to use the client you defined at the top.

See how even though you defined something at the top, and use it as an arg in your function, it chooses to use what you provided in the execution

```js
const a = 42;
function someFn(a) {
console.log(a)
}
someFn()
someFn('foo')
someFn(a)
//logs undefined for the first one as no args were provided, even though a was defined at the top
```